# How to update popup content using leaflet and Ajax (Part 2)

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

*This question is the "episode 2" of this:* [Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157378/how-to-update-popup-content-using-markercluster-with-leaflet/44157857?noredirect=1#comment75335157_44157857/)

Hi !

I'm still having trouble with my map. In fact, I believed the solution in the link above had solve my problem, but I figured out another problem.

My code and my aim are almost the same as the "episode 1" of this question.

As a reminder, I have a Leaflet map that uses MarkerCluster to show ~36.000 markers. Each marker must have a Popup (that appear onclick) which contains many informations.

As they were too many informations to get at one time (I mean to get all points and all informations at one time), I had the idea to get latitude, longitude and a single ID in order to show the Markers on the map. Next, when click on a Popup, the script make an Ajax request to get infos from a Database, using the single ID contains by each marker.

For now, and with the great help of *maximkou*, I can make this happen. My problem is, that only the last ID is consider, so it always request on the same ID and always show the same information (which is not what I try to do).

I tried many things (like getting all the markers on the map, trying to put markers on an array, etc.) but I can't figure out how to get this work.

I don't think it's impossible (but maybe it is), I think I simply lack skill on Javascript.

If you have another solution or idea, I will be glad to test it to !

I will now show you an extract of my current code:

```
function makeMap(pointsToInsert){
    if (typeof map != 'undefined') {
        map.off();
        map.remove();
    }

    var tiles=L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 20,
    }),


    latlng = L.latLng(48.8557, 2.3600);
    var map = L.map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 9, zoomControl:false, layers: [tiles]});
    var arr = JSON.parse(pointsToInsert); //pointsToInsert come from a PHP script call before
    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var a = arr[i];
        var ID = a[0];
        var lat  = a[1];
        var lon  = a[2];

        var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(lat, lon));
        marker.bindPopup(ID);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
        marker.on('click', function () {
            var datas = marker.getPopup().getContent();
            var popup = L.popup()
                .setLatLng(this.getLatLng())
                .setContent("Loading ...")
                .openOn(map); 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getInfos.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data : "id=" + datas,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    popup.setContent(data);
                },

                error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
                    alert("Error");
                },
            });     
        });
    }
    map.addLayer(markers);

 }
```

I need some help here, please

If you want me to be more specific or to add others extract just let me know !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your problem is simple. Simply replace this line:
`var datas = marker.getPopup().getContent();`  with:
`var datas = this.getPopup().getContent();`
You're having this problem because the var marker corresponds to the last marker you've appended to the map.
If you need any more help, please say so.

Comment: Can't believe that was that simple, thank you so much!
As I said, I lack skill on jss...

Thanks again